# Python: How do I display the lowest salaries name

Tags: python

I want to display the lowest salary (which I already figured out) and along with that the name that is affiliated with that lowest salary. It'll look something like this when it prints: The Lowest Salary is: $4500 Produced by: John

```
amount = int(input("How many employees?: "))
if amount <= 0:
    print("You cannot have 0 or less.")
name = []
salary = []
length = len(salary)
mini = 200000
maxi = 0
combined = (name, salary)

for i in range(1, amount + 1):
    employee = input("What is the employee's name?: ")
    name += [employee]
    earned = int(input("How much is the salary? It cannot be less than 0 or over $200,000: "))
    while earned <= 0 or earned >= 200000:
        earned = int(input("How much is the salary? It cannot be less than 0 or over $200,000: "))

        mini = earned
        maxi = earned
    salary += [earned]
    if earned < mini:
        mini = earned
    if earned > maxi:
        maxi = earned

average = sum(salary)/len(salary)

print('The Average Salary is: $',average)
print('The Lowest Salary is: $',mini,'Produced by: ',name)
print('The Highest Salary is: $',maxi,'Produced by: ',name)
```

Answer (score 2):

or you could just find index of the minimum and maximum

```
maxi = salary.index(max(salary))
mini = salary.index(min(salary))

maxsal = salary[maxi]
maxname = name[maxi]

minsal = salary[mini]
minname = name[mini]
```

Comment: This is `O(N^2)` in time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

```
print('The Lowest Salary is: ' + str(mini) + ' Produced by: ' + name)
```

You can also do something like this:

```
print('The Lowest salary is %d Produced by: %s' % (mini, name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have lists like these:

```
In [153]: names=["foo","bar","spam","eggs"]

In [154]: salary=[100,150,50,170]

#highest salary
In [155]: _,name=max(enumerate(names),key=lambda x:salary[x[0]])

In [156]: name
Out[156]: 'eggs'

#Lowest salary
In [157]: _,name=min(enumerate(names),key=lambda x:salary[x[0]])

In [158]: name
Out[158]: 'spam'
```